# postgresql наполнить коллекцию из xml

Tags: postgresql

Сейчас перевожу систему с oracle на postgresql. Есть задача: в процедуру приходит xml нужно ее изменить и отдать назад. В oracle я из xml делал коллекцию с помощью XMLDOM, менял коллекцию потом преобразовывал ее назад в xml. Вопрос как в postgresql преобразовать xml в коллекцию определенного типа или может кто нибудь подскажет другой способ как изменить на ходу xml.

Comment: Можете добавить пример для поиграться? Пример на входе и ожидаемый для этого параметра результат. Кучка функций у pg есть: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-xml.html Но не доводилось XML обрабатывать в базе, в отличии от json.

Comment: Подозреваю, что с json работать было бы удобнее.

Comment: к сожалению мне передается только xml ,поменять это нельзя

Comment: Так что насчёт примера данных и желаемого результата? Я бы поигрался с задачей, но не понятно, что именно надо получить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот ответ на вопрос "как преобразовать xml в коллекцию определенного типа":

```
SELECT  unnest(xpath('text()', node))::text as val,
        unnest(xpath('@id', node))::text::int as id
FROM    unnest(xpath('l',
'<root>
  <l id="1">value 1</l>
  <l id="2">value 2</l>
  <l id="3">value 3</l>
  <l id="4">value 4</l>
 </root>'::xml
)) as node
```

Меняете данные, потом обратно в xml. Наверно это можно назвать "на ходу".